# Conditional attribute with data_bag_item in Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I need to set a default attribute (from a cookbook dependency) to a value that I included in a databag. I want the attribute to be set to the value of data_bag_item or nil if it doesn't exists. In `attribute.rb`:

```
if defined?(data_bag_item('databag', 'item'))
    default["something"]["item"] = data_bag_item('databag', 'item')
else
    default["something"]["item"] = nil
end
```

Later in my own recipe, I'm checking if the variable is set to nil but it seems to fail with this as an error (it's like the condition isn't executed hence the `default["something"]["item"]` is not created)   : `No resource, method, or local variable named 'default' for 'Chef::Recipe "something"'`.

What am I doing wrong here?

(**EDIT** I'm learning Chef as much as I am learning Ruby here. I could totally be mistaken in the use of defined in case of conditionals. I'm open to every critics here!)

Comment: Hi Jean-Philippe. Did you get to do this?? I'm trying to do same, but ....

Comment: @AGL I did not, and I don't get to play with Chef anymore theses days, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the full context of your recipe, but it looks like you should change `default` for `node`. Why? `default` is used to set values that can be changed to each node deployed, but when the you are running the script, you can get the value using `node`. So just change `default["something"]["item"]` for `node["something"]["item"]` where you are checking the variable.

Comment: Precision: `default` is used in attributes files where `node.` is omitted. The `default["something"]` in an attribute file is in fact a call to the `default` method of `node` object, strictly equivalent to `node.default["something"] = "value"`. The method calls a set_or_return method to return the value or set it if one is provided. That's said, avoid using `node.default["something"]` in a recipe as you're going to get only the default value and ignore what could have override it in role or override level.